# How to retrieve password for vpn in Fedora?

Tags: linux, gnome, password, vpn

I have a vpn connection with Cisco Anyconnect. The password is saved, but I need to retrieve it.

I looked at this question [Where does GNOME Network Manager store passwords?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421452/where-does-gnome-network-manager-store-passwords) but it did not help. There is no such field as `password` under the section `[vpn-secret]`. But there is a field called `xmlconfig` with what looks like random data.

How can I retrieve the password?

Actually, retrieving the password is not strictly necessary. What I want is to use the certificates on another computer. I tried copying the three certificate files and the vpn config file found in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` but it did not work. It asked me for the PEM pass phrase when I tried to activate the vpn.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it. I installed "Passwords and keys" (I think it was called seahorse or something) and there I found both the passwords I needed.